# Content on site stacks when browser is resized

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know the best solution for this? When i resize my browser some content gets pushed around and stacked. Here is the site:

http://wildfire-restaurant.com/

Comment: Why is your text dark gray on black?

Comment: It's a work in progress haha, what color text would you suggest?

Comment: Something with contrast.

Comment: If I change it to white will you answer my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `#wrapper` is **extremely wide** (please optimize sites for [1024px](http://screenresolution.org/) or at highest 1280px wide screens) and the `float` is been [abused](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/).

Comment: Thanks for the help. This article about float looks sweet.